# Does keyframe 0 have a "special" use case in blender?

Tags: animation, interface, workflow

In computer programming indexes are (usually) 0 based but the default frame range in Blender is 1 - N which makes me think there could be a reason behind it - similar to last layer being used as a "trash layer" for helper objects - by convention.

So does keyframe 0 have such common "special" use case in workflows (eg. maybe storing default pose) or is it just a UI design choice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'0' may be the starting point for programming, but blender is aimed at *artists*, who may well not have any programming knowledge, for which a zero-starting counting system may not make any sense. Of course, the artist *may* have programming knowledge and be aware of zero-starting counting, but it is not presumed.

Frame '0' has no significance or importance over any other frame. If users choose to consistently do something with that '0' frame then that would be an individual choice, and not a standard convention (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: Ok just wanted to check if it's safe to change this :) btw. I would say 0 counting could make sense even to artists because it's easy to think about distance from start (ie. duration of frame N from start is N-1 if you're 1 based:))